# How to filter with hybrid_property in sqlaclhemy model to decode value from column?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I can not understand how to work with [hybrid properties](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) or what are their limitations.
I have a model where columns stores domain names in ascii. Some of them are idna encoded represented like utf-8:

```
domain.com
xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai # домен.рф
...
```

I want to filter domains with one interface. There is nothing hard with filtering by ASCII string, however non-ascii is different story.
I want to pass substring like `"рф"` to `filter_by_name()` and get expected result - 1 record in thic case with xn--d1acufc.xn--p1ai

```py
class SomeModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table"
    name = Column(String(255))

    @hybrid_property
    def decoded_name(self):
        return self.name.encode("utf-8").decode("idna")

    @decoded_name.expression
    def decoded_name(cls):
        return cls.name.encode("utf-8").decode("idna")

    @classmethod
    def filter_by_name(cls, substring: str):
        with sessionmaker.begin() as s:
            query = s.query(SomeModel)

            if substring.isascii():
                condition = cls.name.like(f"%{substring}%")
            else:
                condition = cls.decoded_name.like(f"%{substring}%")

            query = query.filter(condition)
        return query.all()
```

Buy I get error below. It seems that i should use sqlclhemy func with corresposnd to SQL functions but...what about if I need python routine like encode/decode?

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with SomeModel.name has an attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining an expression:

```py
    @decoded_name.expression
    def decoded_name(cls):
        return cls.name.encode("utf-8").decode("idna")
```

you are at a database level instead of python level. So you should use database operators but it could be tricky or even impossible in your case. Depending on a database, your implementation would be different. For PostgreSQL you probably should use `convert` function: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-string.html and maybe this idna extension (that should be installed in a database): https://github.com/dyninc/postgresql-idn.
Then your expression would look something like that:

```py
    @decoded_name.expression
    def decoded_name(cls):
        return func.idn_idna_encode(func.convert(cls.name, <one_of_utf-8_conversion_type>))
```